# Extract php retorna Undefined variable na página detalhes

Tags: php, array, funções, variáveis, undefined

Estou com o seguinte erro de variável indefinida, estou desenvolvendo um carrinho de compra utilizando URl Amigável. Tudo estava indo bem até que cheguei na parte de retornar todos os índices do meu produto do banco de dados, estou usando a função extract que na teoria era para transformar os índices do meu banco de dados em variáveis, porém não é o que está acontecendo, segue o codigo da minha classe Url.

```
public function PegarUrl($url){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM CADPRO WHERE URL = '$url'";
     $query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $sql) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
     return $query;    
}

public function UrlAmigavel($url){

        if(isset($_GET['url'])){

            $url = $_GET['url'];
            $pasta = ROOT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

            if(substr_count($url,'/') > 0){
                $pagina = explode('/', $url);

                if(file_exists($pasta.$pagina[0].'.php')){
                    include_once $pasta.$pagina[0].'.php';

                }else if($this->PegarUrl($pagina[0])){

                    $dadosprod = (array)$this->PegarUrl($pagina[0]);
                    extract($dadosprod);
                    var_dump($dadosprod);
                    include_once $pasta.'detalhe.php';

                }else{

                    include_once $pasta.'error.php';

                }
            }else{
                if(file_exists($pasta.$url.'.php')){

                    include_once $pasta.$url.'.php';

                }if($this->PegarUrl($pasta[0])){

                    $dadosprod = (array)$this->PegarUrl($url);
                    extract($dadosprod);
                    include_once $pasta.'detalhe.php';

                }else{

                    include_once $pasta.'error.php';

                }
            }
        }else{

            include_once 'home.php';

        }    
    }
```

Depois de fazer isso na minha página detalhes a Url está perfeita porém quando digito os indices do banco que agora deveriam ser variáveis já que utilizei a função extract, eles estão indefinidos e não entendo o porque.

Exemplo:
página detalhe

```
echo $Titulo_Produto
```

retorna indefinido mesmo o índice se chamando Titulo_Produto

Comment: Não está faltando um `sqlsrv_fetch()` que o result da consulta e tranforma ele em um array?

Comment: até fiz isso no método PegarUrl mas não mudou muito =(

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver, estava faltando um fetch_array mesmo.

```
public function PegarUrl($url){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM CADPRO WHERE URL = '$url'";
        $query = sqlsrv_query($this->Conn->Conectar(), $sql) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        if($query){
            if($std = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
                return $std;
            }  
        }    
}
```