# Erro em sistema de login usando SQL Server. resource(7) of type (SQL Server Statement)

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer um sistema de login entre PHP e o SQL Server e está dando o Erro resource(7) of type (SQL Server Statement).

index.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="FormLogin" action="login.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login">Login</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Entre com o seu Login">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="senha">Senha</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Entre com a sua Senha">
   </div>
   <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Limpar</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

login.php

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';
include 'banco-usuario.php';

$usuario = buscaUsuario($conn, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login'), filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha'));
var_dump($usuario);
```

banco-usuario.php

```
$query = "select * from usuario where login = '{$login}' and senha = '{$senha}'";

//$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query); //MySQLi
$resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); //SQL Server


return $resultado;
```

}

Não sei o que fazer para resolver isso.
Quero fazer um sistema que use login.

Comment: Não ta faltanto o `sqlsrv_fetch()` ai? como nessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159600/91)

Comment: Pode ser.
Como ficaria isso? 
return sqlsrv_fetch($resultado);

Comment: Sim, Pode ser um `return sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)`, isso vai retornar apenas uma linha. Se quiser usar prepared statements com sql server veja essa outra [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108610/91)

Comment: Posta de forma que eu possa marcar como resposta

Comment: Deu erro da sua forma mas return sqlsrv_fetch($resultado) funciona.

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem `resource(7) of type (SQL Server Statement)` não é um erro, é uma representação em forma de texto do resource (que pode ser uma consulta). Sua consulta foi processada com `sqlsrv_query()` porém faltou extrair o resultado com `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`.

Para corrigir adicione um return com o resultado já extraido:

```
$resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
return sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```